# SNARK-friendly one-way compression functions

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, zero-knowledge-proofs, compression-function

I'm looking for a one-way compression function that is secure and efficient within a zk-SNARK circuit. The motivation behind this comes from these considerations:

1. SHA256-compression is highly inefficient for SNARKs
2. The Pedersen hash function is efficient, but has an upper input limit of 32 bytes and outputs 32 bytes
3. A Merkle-tree implementation requires a hash function that accepts an input 64 bytes (the 32-byte outputs of two hashes).

Hence I'm looking for a way to securely and efficiently combine two 32-byte values into one 32-byte value.

I'm considering the MiMC hash function for this purpose but it seems like overkill for this purpose; I am already hashing data using Pedersen. Perhaps MiMC with fewer rounds would work well, but perhaps there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Maybe useful? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/are-there-cryptographic-hash-functions-that-can-be-computed-using-only-paper-and

Answer (score 3):

If you just need one-wayness (and not e.g. collision-resistance), want a compression function, and have 64 bytes of inputs, then there is a chance that you are exactly in the regime where [Goldreich's one-way function](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PDF/ow-cand.pdf), with proper choices of parameters, is unbeatable.

Concretely:

- Pick once for all (and store) 256 uniformly random size-5 subsets of $[1,512]$. Denote them $(S_i)_{i \leq 256}$.
- Define the following compression function $f$: on input $x \in \{0,1\}^{512}$, compute each of the 256 bits $y_i$ of the output as $P(x[S_i])$, where $x[S_i]$ denotes the subset of five bits of $x$ indexed by $S_i$, and $P$ denotes the predicate:

$P : (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) \rightarrow x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_3 \oplus x_4\cdot x_5$.

Goldreich's function was thoroughly studied in the last 20 years (see the introduction of [my paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1162.pdf) for an overview). It's security is still far from perfectly understood, but essentially, the security decreases strongly when you look for a very long output. When you actually want a compression function and have a 512-bit input, I believe it should guarantee a clearly sufficient level of security.

As a bonus, observe that this is a completely parallelizable function: all output bits can be computed in parallel.

(of course, there are several other alternatives with low number of multiplications, or small circuit depth, but I think the above looks like a very good choice).