# Are there any paper/human strong crypto systems?

Tags: encryption

Are there any paper/human executed crypto systems that have reasonable strength?
I am aware of a few candidates so far

1. Solitare from Cryptonomicon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitaire_(cipher) (54! unique keys)
2. Off the grid https://www.grc.com/offthegrid.htm (ridiculous amount of entropy, but having plaintext + ciphertext leaks information about the key) (technically seems more like a hash than encryption, because it doesn't seem reversible with the given method, but the grid could probably be used for some encryption method)
3. http://www.ciphergoth.org/crypto/mirdek/
4. One time pads (although answers I'm looking for are more like 1-3))

Comment: For your convenience: besides [“What is the most secure hand cipher?”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-is-the-most-secure-hand-cipher) (of which your question is a duplicate), you might also want to check [“Is there a secure cryptosystem that can be performed mentally?”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/844/is-there-a-secure-cryptosystem-that-can-be-performed-mentally?lq=1)