# Can you help me understand how RC4-52 is done using pen-and-paper?

Tags: encryption, rc4, reference-request, pen-and-paper

I've played a lot with VIC and enjoy its complexity and effectiveness as a field cipher. However, RC4 has caught my attention lately and I've read there is a RC4-52 variant that can be done by hand.

Can anybody describe the rc4-52 algorithm? Is it with a deck of cards and just a swap of the values, or must they still be added somehow?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/844/is-there-a-secure-cryptosystem-that-can-be-performed-mentally

Answer (score 4):

You can do RC4 using a 52-entry table, instead of a 256-entry table.  All you do is change the modulo-256 arithmetic in RC4 to use modulo-52 arithmetic.  There are no special changes needed, and no need to describe a special algorithm.  If you want to see a  description of how to perform it manually using a deck of cards, you can find that here:  http://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@wasabisystems.com/msg00065.html  See also https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sci.crypt/dw3FaK4lf2M

Related: If you've read Neal Stephenson's Cryptonomicon, you may have seen a reference to an encryption algorithm that can also be carried out with a deck of cards.  The cipher is called [Solitaire](https://www.schneier.com/solitaire.html).  It was invented by Bruce Schneier and was apparently inspired by RC4.  However, it has [cryptanalytic weaknesses](http://www.ciphergoth.org/crypto/solitaire/).  (If you haven't read Cryptonomicon, and you like science fiction, check it out: you're in for a treat!)

Keep in mind this is entirely theoretical.  Performing RC4-52 with a deck of cards will be extremely slow and tedious in practice.  And while I don't know of anyone who has seriously studied its security, there are [reasons to doubt](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/sci.crypt/2003-02/1126.html) whether it will be secure against a serious attack.  While it's fun to contemplate, I would not recommend that anyone use this to protect real secrets.